# HTML block inside ajax

Tags: html, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I have this ajax code:

```
$('#ShowMore').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Course/GetCoursesJson",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function () { $('#ShowMore').find('i').show(); },
        success: function (data) {
            **var result = "";**
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                **result = "<div class='col-md-4'>" +
                "<div class='panel panel-default medisce-panel'>" +
                    "<div class='progress-container'>" +
                        "<div class='progress'>" +
                            "<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-custom' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='100' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width:" +value.Complete+"%;'>" +
                                "<span>" + value.Chapter + "</span>" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='badge pull-right'>" + value.Complete + "%</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<h2 class='custom-title-color text-bold'>" + value.Title + "</h2>" +
                    "<img src='http://placehold.it/280x200' alt='"+value.Chapter+"' class='img-responsive margin-20-bottom center-block' />" +
                    "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-custom'>Continue</button>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</div>";**
                $('#ShowResult').append(result);
            });
        }
    })
    .done(function () {
        $('#ShowMore').find('i').delay(1500).fadeOut(500);
    });
});
***************
```

My question is: I want to simplified html code inside result, Can i sent Json data object to external html page or template and than render this html inside my ajax function??? I use asp.net mvc and mvvm.

Comment: what about this? http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Comment: You can return a partial view result from your action method and simply update the DOM with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your action method to return view result instead of json. Have a partial view and from your action method, pass a list of items to the partial view and loop through them and render the same markup you have in your ajax call success event.

```
public ActionResult GetCourses()
{
  List<SomeCourseViewModel> listOfCourse = GetCourseListFromSomeWhere();
  return PartialView("CourseList",listOfCourse);
}
```

Assuming you have a view model called `SomeCourseViewModel` which is a data structure to represent the data for Course.

Now in your partial view (`CourseList.cshtml`) which is strongly typed to a list of your view model, loop through and render the data

```
@model List<SomeCourseViewModel>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <div class='col-md-4'>
     <span>@item.Chapter</span>
     <div>@item.Complete %</div>
  </div>
}
```

*I just added simple markup. You may replace it with the markup you want*.

Now your ajax call's `success` event can be simple and clean as this

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Course/GetCourses",      
        type: "GET",      
        success: function (result) {
           $('#ShowResult').html(result);
        }
 });
```